# How to Install .ipa file to iPhone from Web Link?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa

I have created one enterPrise App. And I followed the steps form the below [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html).

I also gave correct paths for Manifest file also.

After exporting App to the Server, If I use that link to install that .ipa file to my iPhone,

It's showing like the Below image.

How to install that .ipa file to iPhone without using third party tools or itunes connect?

Image showing like this while click on .ipa file link
[image: Image showing like this while click on .ipa file link]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204460) is helpful.

Comment: hi shallow Thought first of all the app not at all downloading/installing to iPhone. After download/install only we can follow your steps @ shallowThought

But here the ipa file not at all installing or downloading.

Comment: What's your url like? Does it look like this? `href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://path/to/your/manifest.plist"`

Comment: https://www.diawi.com/

Comment: @RSP Did you get your solution from my answer?

Answer (score 4):

You just need to enable the **over the air installation** while creating ipa file.

Check attached screen shots, it will help you more.
[image]

You can provide your ipa, small icon and big icon url in second steps.

[image]

Once you are done with this steps, you will get **manifest.plist** and **YOUR_NAME.ipa**.

Now you are ready to upload application. You can put both file on url which you enter in second steps. Then create one html file and write below code on button click:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=YOUR_MANIFEST_PATH/manifest.plist">Tap Here to Install<br />APPNAME<br />INSTALLED</a>
```

Open html url in your device and installed application.

Best way to upload ipa and manifest is **DROPBOX**. You can upload both on dropbox **Public** folder and then you can get link and use it.
Cheers...

Comment: hi Nirmal, i did already what you menction in this. i have uploaded Both ipa file and manifest.plist file to my microsoft share point Account.
i have given all urls correctly in manifest.plist file.
from there it generate one manifest.plist share url.

i have placed that URL in href path.

but when i click on "Tap Here to Install" nothing is happening.

My doubt is is that problem with Microsoft share point Account urls?

Comment: yes its same path only. is there any free webserver available to check?

Comment: As we showed in screen shots for HTML. I think issue is there. When you load html file, then it will only button with name, not .ipa file. Put html on dropbox and check it out.

Comment: hi previously i did like that after i changed as you said.

Comment: Possible to give me html file.

Comment: finally i got by making it through dropbox.

Sharepoint urls not work for this.

thanks for your suggestions nirmal.

Comment: Wonderful. Cheers

Comment: is it still works on latest iphones in 2021 ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have the enterprise dev account. And when you archive, export enterprise ipa.
The following steps are how I deploy my enterprise ipa package.
There are some files you should provide, and all put on the server which is support https.
1. appIcon size of 512x512
2. appIcon size of 57x57
3. ipa package
4. a manifest.plist. In the plist file you should set the software-package to where the ipa address in the server, display-image(icon 57x57) and full-size-image(icon 512x512).

When all the files have done, you can download the ipa in the safari use the URL:
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://yourserveraddress/manifest.plist